# Sub graph isomorphism

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, igraph

In igraph or networkx, what is the fastest way  to find all simple paths of length 4 in a sparse directed graph?  One way is to make a graph of a simple path of length 4 and use the subgraph isomorphism vf2 function. Is this the best/fastest way?

I don't have a source node, I would like all simple paths of length 4 that exist in the whole graph.

In my data there are likely to be very few such paths and I would like to be able to iterate over them efficiently.

Comment: Is "find all simple paths of length 4" should be read as "find all pathes that are shortest between nodes and of length 4"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a function like this:

```
def simple_paths(start, length, visited=[]):
    if length==0:
        yield(visited + [start])
    else:
        for child in children(start):
            if child not in visited:
                for path in simple_paths(child, length-1, visited + [start]):
                    yield(path)
```

You can list all simple paths of length 4 by calling

```
for start in nodes():
    for path in simple_paths(start, 4):
        print path
```

The above assumes that `nodes()` returns an iterable of all nodes in the graph, and that `children(x)` returns an iterable of the children of node `x`.

[image]

Applying the `simple_paths()` function to the above graph correctly yields:

```
['5', '9', '3', '1', '0']
['6', '5', '9', '3', '1']
['6', '5', '3', '1', '0']
['9', '5', '3', '1', '0']
```

This demonstrates that the function:

- respects directed edges (e.g. it does not choose `['6', '5', '1', '3', '9']`)
- only chooses simple paths (e.g. it does not choose `['6', '5', '3', '1', '5']`)

Comment: For networkx, you can replace `children(start)` with `nx.neighbors(G, start)` and `nodes()` with `nx.nodes(G)`. I also think it would make more sense to rename children() to neighbors(), as the graph is not necessarily a tree.

Comment: I think the only issue with this answer is that it uses recursion.  That doesn't seem to be the efficient option.

Comment: I don't know igraph or networkx or how the graph is represented, but if it is using linked lists, this method of iterating over all paths of a given length in a sparse graph is very efficient and essentially O(N).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, let's solve more simpler problem  - calculate number of paths of length 4.

1) Let A be an adjacency matrix of the given graph. `A[i][j] = 1` if there exist an edge between vertices I and J and 0 otherwise. `A^N` gives number of paths of length `N` for some fixed length.

2) matrix *squaring* looks like

```
init(RES,0);
for(row=1;N)
      for(col=1;N)
         for(common=1;N)
             RES[row][col] + = a[row][common]*a[common][col];
```

The physical meaning is such construction is the following: 
 For each degree `deg` of given matrix `A`, `A[i][j]` stores numbers of paths with length =  `deg` from `i to j`. At the first stage adjacency matrix is just storing number of paths of length=1. When you multiply `A^N to A` you are 
trying to extend paths of length `N to N+1`.

`a[row][common]*a[common][col]` can be enterpreted as "there `a[row][common]` ways of len=1 from `row` to `common` and `a[common][col]` ways of len=1 from `common` to `col`. According to combinatorics multiplication principle number of ways with len=1 from row to col is `a[row][common]*a[common][col]`".

Now important modification. You want to list all paths not just count them! So, A[i][j] is not integer number but `vector` or `ArrayList` of integers. Replace `RES[row][col] + = a[row][common]*a[common][col]` with `RES[row][col].push_back(cartesian_product(a[row][common],a[common][col]))` Complexity of just counting paths is `matrix multiplication*degree` = N^3*degree. Applying binary exponentiation you can get N^3*log(degree). In our case degree=4, log(4) = 2, 2~4 - doesn't matter. But now you can't just multiply 2 numbers you should do cartesian product of vectors  - paths of len N. So complexity increases to N in common case but in our case to 4)

If you have some questions you are welcome.

Comment: I am  looking for simple paths. I think your matrix squaring method counts any paths.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only paths of exactly length 4 you need, you can easily find your results by first finding all length two paths, then stitching pairs of them together. In theory you could do this for arbitrary lengths, but it would be messier (you'd probably end up building several power-of-two lists, then combining them to get other lengths).

I'm not very fluent with NetworkX or iGraph, but here's how I'd do it for a graph specified by adjacency lists (where `n1[i]` is an iterable containing all the nodes that have an edge going to them from node `i`). I think it should be easy to map this to the appropriate API.

```
n1 = adjacency_lists()
n2 = [[(a, b) for a in x for b in n1[a] if i != b] for i, x in enumerate(n1)]
n4 = [[(a, b, c, d) for (a, b) in x for (c, d) in n2[b]
       if i != c and i != d and a != c and a != d]
      for (i, x) in enumerate(n2)]
```

The `if` clauses in the list comprehensions ensure that the paths are simple. I've assumed that there are no edges from a node to itself. If that's not true, add to the `n2` list comprehension an extra `if i != a` clause (before `for b in n1[a]`) and add `a != b` to the existing `if` clause.

You can output the paths with:

```
for i, paths in enumerate(n4):
    for a, b, c, d in paths:
        print("{}->{}->{}->{}->{}".format(i, a, b, c, d))
```

The computation should have asymptotic running time `O(N*D^4)` where `N` is the number of nodes and `D` is the maximum degree of the nodes (which is the best you can do, I think). I doubt there's a substantially faster solution in pure Python. A solution that uses graph library calls that are implemented in C may be faster by a (possibly large) constant factor.

Comment: Thank you. Will a single high degree node slow it down a lot?

Comment: I don't think a single high-degree node is too bad, but if you had four nodes with degrees much higher than average you could get a worse runtime than the average degree to the fourth power if they connect to each other. I'm not sure it can be restated in terms of the average degree.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the relevant docs here :)

[Simple Paths in NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths)

essentially it's just a tree search of some sort

you can use the [list of nodes](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.nodes.html#networkx.classes.function.nodes) and do this

```
list_of_nodes = nodes(my_graph)
for mysource in list_of_nodes:
    for mytarget in list_of_nodes:
        if source != target:
             print all_simple_paths(my_graph,source=mysource,target=mytarget, cutoff=4)
```

If you want all the shortest paths of length 4 you can use [``all_pairs_shortest_path_```](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path)

```
paths = all_pairs_shortest_path(my_graph,cutoff=4)
for k,v in paths:
    if len(paths[k][v]) == 4:
        print paths[k][v]
```

There is no real command built in to generate all the simple paths of a certain length as the only way to find that is to generate a tree from every node, e.g. doing a modified version of my for loop above since that uses a modified depth-first search.

---

> "A path with no repeated vertices is called a simple path" - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29)

If you would like a [paper citation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1084515). The only way to check for simple paths is to check from each node. If you have a graph with 90000 elements; there is no other way to check if two connect :/. The 'target' is really not consequential as it's just another cutoff, though if you have a large number of nodes it can make a difference so you're right there :).

```
   " def _all_simple_paths_graph(G, source, target, cutoff=None):
        if cutoff < 1:
            return
        visited = [source]
        stack = [iter(G[source])]
        while stack:
            children = stack[-1]
            child = next(children, None)
            if child is None:
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
            elif len(visited) < cutoff:
                if child == target:
                    yield visited + [target]
                elif child not in visited:
                    visited.append(child)
                    stack.append(iter(G[child]))
            else: #len(visited) == cutoff:
                if child == target or target in children:
                    yield visited + [target]
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()"
```

code above from [networkx docs](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.html)

to modify it in order to generate the DFS without the 'target' cutoff you can use:

```
   def _all_simple_paths_graph(G, source, target, cutoff=None):
        if cutoff < 1:
            return
        visited = [source]
        stack = [iter(G[source])]
        while stack:
            children = stack[-1]
            child = next(children, None)
            if child is None:
                stack.pop()
                visited.pop()
            elif len(visited) < cutoff:
                #if child == target:
                #    yield visited + [target]
                #elif child not in visited:
                 if child not in visited:
                    visited.append(child)
                    stack.append(iter(G[child]))
            #else: #len(visited) == cutoff:
                #if child == target or target in children:
                #    yield visited + [target]
                #stack.pop()
                #visited.pop()
```

---

Hope that works for you :)

Comment: That says "Generate all simple paths in the graph G from source to target." which is not what I am looking for.  I don't have a source node in my problem.

Comment: it's a directed graph, you can set the source to any node and the target to any other. this is more specific then you need; that's never a problem

Comment: My problem is to find all simple paths of length 4. Not all simple paths starting from some particular node.

Comment: Iterate thru all the nodes and find the paths from each.

Comment: The poster is asking for any simple path, not just shortest paths.

Comment: So make two new nodes, a source and a sink, and add edges from them to each other node. Then ask for simple paths of length 6 from source to sink. Honestly, though, if you're concerned about speed, you should just write your own traversal.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: no, you don't. You call a function named `all_pairs_shortest_path`, which calculates shortest paths only. I.e. if a pair of vertices are connected by a path of length 3 and another one of length 4, you will not find the second one.